# Kubernetespodoperator - how do I map an existing directory to one inside the image

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, volume

When I run the docker image locally I run this, how can I do the equivalent volume mapping with Kubernetespodoperator?

docker run -v /Users/sharonst/PycharmProjects/gcp_datawarehouse/Privacy_Manager:/usr/src/app/Privacy_Manager

What I want to map in airflow would be

-v /home/airflow/gcs/dags/Privacy_Manager:/usr/src/app/Privacy_Manager

Answer (score 0):

What will you do after mounting? Just chill